# Is "You were going to <noun> and <verb>." grammatical?

Tags: nouns, prepositions, infinitives

In the song ["An English Teacher"](https://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/byebyebirdie/anenglishteacher.htm) from the musical "Bye, Bye Birdie," Rosie sings to Albert `You were going to NYU / and become an English teacher.`

I would parse this as `You were (going to NYU) and (going to become an English teacher).` but I'm not sure if `become` is used as an infinitive here, and (if so) whether `to` can be "distributed" like this between a noun and an infinitive verb.

(The line is in a song, so I suppose some creative liberties can be taken with the grammar. However, I thought it was a bit funny that this (possibly) ungrammatical sentence was in a song with such a title.)

Comment: It's a zeugma and this one, at least, is non-standard. 'To' is being forced into two very different roles; I believe some grammarians say they're different parts of speech while others claim the infinitive marker should be considered a marginal preposition, possibly on etymological grounds.

Comment: For an example of an even more outrageous [zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis), consider this line from [Flanders and Swann's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanders_and_Swann) _Have some Madeira, M'dear_: "When he said 'God in heaven', she made no reply, up her mind, and a dash for the door".

Comment: @Edwin Alternatively, and I think more naturally in this instance, we could treat *and* as conveying the sense of ‘*(in order) to*’ in the original quote.